# react get data from rest api with axios and and useEffect redering empty array plus array with data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to render data from rest api site, I can get all info without issues, but is duplicating the data with an empty array first and this is creating a conflict with the map() function.

when I do a console logo I can see the duplication. what I need is to only get the array that has the data and the empty one or how can I select the array with data, since for somereason when i used the map() function I get error because its reading the empty array

[image: duplication]

useFetchData.js

```
import { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import http from '../../services/httpservices';
import config from '../../services/config.json';

const useFetchData = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
 const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const { data: response } = await http.get(config.apiEndpoint);
    setData(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
   setLoading(false);
  };

   fetchData();
  }, []);
 return {
  data,
  loading,
 };
};

export default useFetchData;
```

customsite.jsx

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react';
  import Modal from './reusable/modal';
  import useFetchData from './hooks/useFetchData';

  const Customsite = ()=> {

const {
    data,
    loading,
  } = useFetchData();


  console.log(data);

return(
    <div>
     <p> we here </p>

            
               </div>
     )
     }

  export default Customsite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to wait until the data has loaded to get the full array, you must condition the console log to loading === false

```js
!loading && console.log(data);
```

the same goes with the map function you want to use. you need to add this condition. Either that or test if data.length > 0